# Skip blank lines from CSV using JMeter Csv config

Tags: jmeter

I have CSV file which has some blank lines.
Is there is setting in JMeter CSV data config to exclude blank lines and read only those lines which has values.

Please help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, the options are in:

1. Remove blank lines from the CSV file using [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) and [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), example code:

   ```
   def content = new File('test.csv').readLines()

   def notblank = content.findAll { it != '' }

   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeLines(new File('test.csv'), notblank)
   ```
2. Use [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) to skip the blank lines via [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3)

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${variable_from_csv}" != "",)}
   ```