# how to skip blank values in http post body in Jmeter while reading data from csv?

Tags: http, post, jmeter, jsr223

Below is my sample body in jmeter. I tried using the JSR223 pre processor with below code but its removing the blank values only for the first csv row. How do i remove all blank values coming from my csv file? wham am i doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

```
**[def request = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
def newRequest = evaluate(request.inspect())
request.each { entry ->
    if (entry.getValue().equals('')) {
        newRequest.remove(entry.getKey())
    }
}
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(newRequest).toPrettyString(), '')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)][1]**
```

http body:
{

```
"number": "${number}",
"marker": "${market}",
"description": "${description}"
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip blank lines from CSV using JMeter Csv config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66595590/skip-blank-lines-from-csv-using-jmeter-csv-config)

Comment: No. My requirement was to skip sending blank fields. CSV file does not have any blank lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than 1 iteration in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) you will need to revisit your approach to removing and adding back the request body.

Suggested code change:

```
def data = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()
def request = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
def newRequest = evaluate(request.inspect())
request.each { entry ->
    if (entry.getValue().equals('')) {
        newRequest.remove(entry.getKey())
    }
}
def body = new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument('', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(newRequest).toPrettyString(), '', false)
body.setAlwaysEncoded(false)
data.addArgument(body)
sampler.setArguments(data)
```

More information:

- [HTTPSamplerBase source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.java)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)